# can we use single trigger for two sql table?

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1] ON [dbo].[CommonTable]
FOR UPDATE
UPDATE [CommonTable] 
SET 
    [StatusCode] = 'New Value'
WHERE 
[RecId] = 'rec id value'
update [commontable2]
SET 
    [StatusCode] = 'New Value'
WHERE 
[RecId] = 'rec id value'
```

Comment: You've answered your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

No. Create trigger assigns a trigger for one table. But you can create a procedure, and you can call it from the 2 table's triggers body.